# how you can find the coordinates of the point on the graph $f(x)=3x^2-7x+4$ where the tangent line is parallel to the line $5x+y=3$

Tags: calculus

How you can find the coordinates of the point on the graph $f(x)=3x^2-7x+4$ where the tangent line is parallel to the line $5x+y=3$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Telling us will (a) show us what you know, so that we can better help you, and (b) convince us that you're putting in at least as much effort as we are.

Comment: If $(u,v)$ be that point, then $\left\{\frac{df}{dx}\right\}_{(u,v)}=$ slope of line.

Answer (score 2):

To begin, from $f(x)=3x^2-7x+4$, differentiating $\implies f^{\prime}(x)=6x-7$

For $y=3-5x$, the gradient or derivative of this line is $-5$.

The gradient of the line $y=3-5x$ is equal to the gradient of the curve $f(x)$.

The answer is given in $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$, see if you can get there.

> This implies that $f^{\prime}(x)=-5$. Therefore, $6x-7=-5 \implies x=\frac{1}{3}$. To get the $y$-coordinate substitute $x=\frac13$ into $f(x)$ $\implies f\left(\frac13\right)=3\left(\frac13\right)^2-7\left(\frac13\right)+4=2$. So the coordinates where the tangent line is parallel to $y=3-5x$ is $\color{blue}{\left(\frac13,2\right)}$